# How to compare and merge two MS word documents in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, ms-word, frontend

We have a requirement in which we need to upload two Microsoft word documents and then, compare and merge it into a document with the non-repeating data in the document in Javascript.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to merge the 2 documents using Javascript? of do you mean that you want to upload 2 documents to the server and process it on the server and return a new word document as outcome? If it's the latter one then it can be done. The first one is impossible i think.

Comment: The requirement here is to merge it all in JavaScript alone.